# storing multiple values inside field in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

It came to my mind that is it possible to store more than one value inside one cell in a mysql table using php and then retrieve every value through php.I will provide an example to make it more clear.

**Example:**

Suppose, i have the first column of **text** type and the very first field of that column i.e. `mysqltable[0][0]`. Is there any way i can save multiple values inside this field in this way  `value1;value2;value3;` and so on in the rest of the fields inside the column ?if yes, then how can i do this and retrieve the very same using **php**?

Comment: Yes u can along with any seperator like commas... But its not normalized

Comment: Yes it's possible, and it always raises a mass of issues and performance problems, and requires a lot more complexity in your code to access/update/etc that data; don't do it..... normalise your data properly

Comment: 1. you can store`,` separated string values (on fetching time explode by `,` and get all values in form of array).

2. you can save serialized array into the fields(on fetching time un-seriaialize it). 
3.you can store json-encoded data (on fetching time decode it)

Comment: yeah but still i would like to know how it is done ? @MarkBaker

Comment: this is not the correct way to do it....

Comment: If you really need to know how to do it, then you make the field a varchar or text column, and when you write to it, you write a string value...... there's no magic method to do it, because it's no different to writing any string to a varchar or text column

Comment: If you do really want to get clever, then upgrade to MySQL 5.7 and use the JSON datatype..... at least you can apply indexes to elements within that

Comment: I didn't know about the json data type. But it still seems like a bad idea. I remember when it was all XML, thinking how clever it was that you could parse xml inside MySQL. Look, now XML's dead and MySQL lives on!

Comment: If you don't want to search on the data, or don't mind doing your own indexing, look at Php's serialize, unserialize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [storing multiple values in one field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487439/storing-multiple-values-in-one-field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can insert values in your database. You should try to implode that string with `,` separated string values to insert that and fetch that values in a your form with `explode()` function.